# Ruby Nokogiri select

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Good day everyone. I need help selecting  *+ Show all 4* and print it from Ruby Nokogiri. Any one help me out? Thanks!

`<span data-plusbox-cid="8460070" href="/shopping/product/13207837492092556120/plusbox/8460070?sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjuu-3dn5baAhXCtFMKHRg7DhoQhxoIRg" data-plusbox-state="hidden" jsaction="pdpb.tpb"> <span class="shop__a AFgVce" id="os-plusbox-show-8460070"> + Show all 4 </span> <span class="shop__a AFgVce" id="os-plusbox-hide-8460070" style="display:none"> - Hide all </span> </span>
<span class="shop__a AFgVce" id="os-plusbox-show-8460070"> + Show all 4 </span>`

Which element should I select?

`puts html.css('????').text`

Comment: Probably not your fault, just wanna point out that `id="os-plusbox-show-8460070"` on two different elements is a crime. Or should be.

Comment: How did you fetch that HTML?

Comment: How about: `html.css(':contains("+ Show all 4")')` ?

Answer (score 0):

First find the element by xpath css slector

```
el = (html.xpath './/span[@data-plusbox-cid=8460070]').first # get first html object that matches this pattern

el.text # get text isnide of the HTML tag.

# outputs:  "\n\t + Show all 4 \n\t - Hide all \n"

el.children[1].text #targets 1st child of outer span
```

There are probably other ways but this should get you started.

If you wanna just find an element by the text inside it's HTML tag:

```
html.css('span').select{|n| n.text.include?'Show all 4'}.first.text
```

If you're trying to parse an HTLM document that is largely rendered by javascript, you won't be able to do until after the javascript has executed on the page and the DOM has been updated.  You can see the plain html of the google url you've commented. Here it is with the CSS and JS stripped out and so the data you're looking for in the HTML body won't be found.

https://jsfiddle.net/mp0y5bkm/

As you can see a text search on that document doesn't even contain the word `Show`

Comment: undefined method 'text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: in your case replace `doc` with `html`

Comment: doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/shopping/product/10109509872412212217'))

Comment: ok but that page will not have the css selector you've indicated, so what else do you want/need?  Nokogiri allows you to query html/xlm based on css selectors. It's not a mind reader.

Comment: That's where the 'Show all' is located.

Comment: The code I've posted works with an HTML document rendered.  If you're trying to do it in ruby it will only pull the HTML available, not data rendered with javascript. If you examine the HTML from the URL it will NOT have the text you're looking for until after loading and running the javascript. If you're talking about https://www.google.com/shopping